# Problema con el password de mysql-server

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, servidor

Acabo de instalar mysql-server en ubuntu y al querer entrar me pide password, el cual en la instalacion no me pidio ningun password. necesito ayuda con esto llevo mas de 1 dia bucando y haciendo cosas y nada funciona. se los agradezco.

> **Versiones:** **1** Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
>   **2** mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine
>   wrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno pude solucionar esto, si alguien mas adelante le pasa el mismo error aqui esta la solucion:
1. Desinstale todo mysql de mi sistema con el siguiente comando:

```
1. sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common
2. sudo apt-get autoremov
3. sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

Bueno ahora un poco de explicación para lo que hicimos.

— purge : Eliminamos los paquetes y los archivos de configuración.
remove : desinstala los paquetes.
autoremove : Fuerza para eliminar los paquetes que se instalaron de forma automatica debido a las necesidades de las dependencias de otros paquetes y ahora ya no son necesarios.

Luego instalo otra vez mysql pero con estos comandos:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Los pasos necesarios a seguir los encontre en esta pagina:
[instalar mysql con usuarios y contraseñas](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 3):

Yo he seguido el procedimiento tal cual y he podido resetear la password del administrador.

1º Te creas el fichero sql con el comando para cambiarle la password
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';

2º Paras mysql 
kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`

3º  Arrancas mysql con el fichero sql que creaste en el arranque.
mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &

Aunque realmente me salió mas a cuenta arrancar el mysql con el parámetro --skip-grant-tables 
En ese momento, ya no te pide la password al entrar, le cambias la password al root, lo paras y arrancas ya sin el parámetro.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Veo que en la ultima versión de mysql-server hay que hacer la configuración manual del servidor e incluso para mysql-workbench me sirvió mucho y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Bueno a mi me paso lo mismo, tienes que saber que solo hay unica manera de accesar al usuario root  y es que cambies primero como super usuario, despues accedas a la base de datos y por ultimo crees otro usuario para poder entrar directamente. O siemplemente siempre usar desde el paso 1 a 3 para trabajar con la base de datos cada vez que quieras usarla

1. Cambia como root

   sudo -i
2. Ingresa a la base de datos

   mysql -u root -p
3. Estaras en el BD como root, aquí ya puedes usar las bases de datos
4. Crea un nuevo usuario

   create user nombre de usuario identified by 'contrasena' -->**(structure)

   create user root1 identified by 'contrasena' -->ejemplo (example)
5. Ingresa con este usario creado, pero cada vez que quieras entrar a la base de datos , tendras que cambiar antes a root con "sudo -i" y despues ingresar a la base de datos.
6. Probar si el nuevo perfil funciona

   mysql -u root1 -p
7. Ingresar clave, dar enter y debería poderse ver la base con el nuevo usuario.

Más informacion:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pdn-tAFyGjo